# cannot run JOCL samples downloaded from jocl.org. (OPENCL for java)

Tags: java, jar, opencl, jocl

I have downloaded the sample file from [jocl.org](http://jocl.org) and compiled it without problems (`c:\javac -cp c:\jocl.jar JOCLSample.java`)

When I tried to run it (`c:\java -cp c:\jocl.jar JOCLSample`), some errors occurred:

```
C:\Users\Ruoyu>java -cp C:\j.jar JOCLSample
Error: Could not find or load main class JOCLSample
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

If `JOCLSample.class` is in `C:\Users\Ruoyu`, change your `-cp` parameter to `C:\j.jar;C:\Users\Ruoyu`